# How to make my JAX-RS webservice remember my login?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, stateful

I created a very simple REST webservice in Java by using JAX-RS. And have a client make Ajax calls to that webservice to login and get the login information.

JAX-RS Code

```
@Path("/netsuite")
public class myRESTWebService{
   @GET
   @Path("/login/{userName}")
   public String login(@PathParam("userName") String userName){
      //here I have to save that userName in some session so that I can use it in below function
   }


   @GET
   @Path("/getUserName")
   public String getUserName(){
      //here I have to return the above username
   }  
}
```

I know REST webservices are stateless, how can I make it stateful. I tried Google search whole day, didn't helped me much.

How can I make it stateful ?

Comment: Are you using CDI in your project?

Comment: Get access to the HttpSession and save there what you want...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the [HttpSession](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) and store the username like this:

```
@GET
@Path("/login/{userName}")
public String login(@PathParam("userName") String userName, @Context HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("userName", userName);
}
```

But I strongly recommend to rethink why you need state in a stateless application and take a look at [Java EE Security Concepts](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncbx.html).

Unrelated: Classes in Java always start with a capital Letter.